# A solution for payments using php and paypal and store in a mysql db?

Tags: php, forms, post, paypal, paypal-ipn

I looking for a solution for visitors to pay using Paypal for setup there ads on my website.
I want when the visitor has fill in the form (POST) and then click on the Paypal Button they will leave my site to the Paypal site for pay and after a successful payment redirect to my thanks page like thanks.php and all information in the form will be stored in a mysql db.

I have looked at the code example at the Paypal Developer site for Paypal (IPN), i don´t now if that is right solution to do?.

i don´t actually know how the form will be stored in the db after a successfull payment using Paypal? Please can someone help me some code example how i can store the form inputs like name, email, adsinfo, price and a image to the db after the payment?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use IPN(Instant Payment Notification) there you can update or insert the values to mysql. This page will execute after completing the payment its running in the server not in user browser, So its the better way to handle

Comment: Please can you help with a code example in php using the Paypal IPN to store name, email, adsinfo, price and a uploaded image from a form. To the example Paypal Email: demo@demo.com?

Comment: Best way to store (insert) all the values form page itself in mysql table add one more field called status. Based on the IPN payment status update the status field only